# How to avoid empty documents in a Firestore query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display some data which is hosted under a subcollection `coll1` that exist in `doc1` using this code:

```
val query = db!!.collection("coll1").document(doc1)
    .collection("coll2").orderBy("field1", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

The problem is when I use this code, the `doc1` variable isn't generated yet so I get this error:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments

How can I avoid this error till I generate `doc1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the exact names of all collections and documents in order to perform a query, so your query should only be performed after you have the string value for `doc1` that identified the document where the subcollection has been organized.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you Doug!